# Hide ID in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm busy with a webpage to make it possible to reply a question. I have 2 pages in written in PHP.

results.php: a while loop that fetchs all rows from the database incl. their id's. Each question has its own id.

```
<li><a href="answer.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>">Answer this question: </a></li>
```

reply.php: this shows a question according its id, but I don't want to show the id in the $_POST like: reply.php?id=1. I have tried to hide the id, through put it in the session but that doesn't work.
Can someone help me out?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['answer']))
```

{

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
/*


Each id that belongs to its question needs to changed when you click on    another link it has to be looped.

Each time when we click on the answer link, we get the same id constantly but that is not our purpose.

I tried to give in the results.php file to give the id together with the url to avoid SQL Injections.

I placed the ids out of loops and placed it in session. Only the $_SESSION['vid'] stays the same even if I click on another answer link.


*/
```

}

Comment: please post a MCVE showing us what you tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if you d $_POST , it will not show the data in URL,

Answer (score 3):

```
<Form methode="POST"></form>
```

will stop showing the `?id=1`. but you won't get infomation out of url with `$GET['']` anymore.You need to use `$_GET['']` to get the infomation out of the url. You can try to use a php rewrite rule to rewrite the url, so it won't show the id anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST[""]` will not show any information in the URL. Although in your case if you want to post data from your database on the same page (as example a blog) you should be using `$_GET[""]`.